# Inverting the carry flag on an M6800

Tags: assembly, 6800

Are there any tricks that can be used to invert the carry flag on the 6800, in as few bytes as possible?

This is the shortest subroutine I've come up with, which is straight forward:

```
INVC:  BCS CLEAR
       SEC
       RTS
CLEAR: CLC
       RTS
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shortest coding  (I came up so far):

```
   Instruction Bytes Cycles
   TPA         1     2       Transfer P(rocessor status) to (accumulator) A
   EOR A,#$01  2     2       Invert bit 0 (carry bit) using exclusive OR
   TAP         1     2       Transfer (accumulator) A back to P(rocessor status)
              ---   ---
               4     6
```

Of course this will only work if A is available.

Without your solution is a good start. Speed should be the same.

---

And then Supercat came along with [two really nifty ideas](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14439/inverting-the-carry-flag-on-an-m6800/14441?noredirect=1#comment47754_14441) using ROL/ROR to get access to carry and flip it:

Solution A:

```
   Instruction Bytes Cycles
   ROL A       1     2       Shift C(arry) into acc A bit 0, save bit 7 in carry
   EOR A,#$01  2     2       Invert bit 0 (carry bit) using exclusive OR
   ROR A       1     2       Shift bit 0 back into C(arry) and restore bit 7
              ---   ---
               4     6
```

It is as compact and fast as my solution, but preserves the content of acc A

Solution B:

```
   Instruction Bytes Cycles
   ROL B       1     2       Shift C(arry) into acc B bit 0
   INC B       1     2       Increment by 1 always flips the lowest bit (*)
   ROR B       1     2       Shift bit 0 back into C(arry)
              ---   ---
               3     6
```

(* `0 + 1 = 1`; `1 + 1 = (1)0`. The cool ways of binary)

This as well preserves A (but destroyes B) but saves another byte, while still performing in 6 cycles.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106827/discussion-on-answer-by-raffzahn-inverting-the-carry-flag-on-an-m6800).